# Duplicate Buttons in xml file using android studio java

Tags: java, android

**Duplicate buttons are in my xml file which is fragment_employee2**
I'm only creating one xml file to list out all the list in one xml

Here is the code in my https://gist.github.com/Umen14/8d1a205f016fa970369d37f37d4bf15d

And here are the images:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsi2o.png)

I tried by removing here and there but the code seems to be the same but there is a problem in the onclick listener in my EmployeeFragment.java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYECN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is showing duplicate because you are using same xml in recyclerView item   as well as activity layout. which `R.layout.fragment_employee2` in your case. You need to define different layout in EmployeeAdapter without button. This will resolve you issue.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked where I create another xml file where to list for the recycler view to remove the buttons and called out employeeviewholder to change them back to textview...Thank you Umesh for the heads up...It was a simple mistake which took me finding for hours. It is true to let others to see your problem. Have a great day my friend